# Uncaught ReferenceError: SayHi is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there a way to use existing `html/javascript` pages with angular?

I have several html pages that have embedded JavaScript functions and depending on the pages that is needed I would like to dynamically render that page in an angular component.

I created a "**dynamicpage**" component where 
my `dynamicpage.component.html` would simply have one tag

```
<div [innerHtml]="templateHtml | sanitizeHtml"></div>
```

`dynamicpage.component.ts` would set `templateHtml` value to something like

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SayHi() {
  alert("Hi.");
}
</script>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="SayHi();" value="Hi" />
</body>

</html>
```

The html on its own runs fine in browser when saved as `*.htm` by but when I run it through angular and click the button I get

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: SayHi is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

does "SayHi" function have to reside in the `dynamicpage.component.ts` file?

I reviewed several post with similar issues and most suggested a scope issue but their solutions didn't work for me.

I am new to angular so I am not sure if my approach is possible.

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide.

[image: I added screen shot of the inspect window.]

Comment: Angular application is a regular web site. It already has html, body, head tags. Your code renders these tags again inside a div element. So, you are getting an invalid markup. You wrote that you found several solutions, but they don't work for you. What solutions did you find and why don't they work for you?

Comment: suggestions from others were regarding syntax errors and ensuring the function was a global function and didn't have any wrappers around it.

Comment: Maybe you need [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: I added a screen shot of the inspect window with html as shown above (with html/head tags) but the inspect window doesn't show them.  Don't see anything about invalid markup but I did try removing the html, head and body tags in my htm and get the same uncaught reference error.

Comment: sayHi function rendered dynamically, so it wont compile by browser, that's why getting error "undefined function". So Attach sayHi function in head section while rendering.

Comment: thanks, I got it to work by separating the html markup and script text into 2 dynamic text strings and adding them independently to the document.